# how to set MIME type for video and html file?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

I have use this code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html"); 
StartActivity(i);

but samsung device show the video player onaction using.
i want to show only install browser.
```

Comment: Can you show us an exemple of a link you are trying to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: (removed old answer)

When you fire an Intent of ACTION_VIEW, in case there are other applications registered to this action using their manifest file, assuming those were run at least once on your device they will show up in a chooser. There are a variety of applications that register for some Intent actions without properly filtering the data type like in your case and are ignoring these parameters.

Comment: i thing open default browser but don't show all install browser.

Answer (score 3):

> My problem solve by using createChooser() in Samsung device.
>
> for browser.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chose browser"));
```

> for video.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
intent.setType("video/mp4");
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chose browser"));
```